# regex password validation angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am new to angular js. I have created a login screen. I need to validate my password. it should contain one special character from `-'$@£!%*#?&'` and at least one letter and number. As of now it accepts all special characters without any limitations. I have following code

```
if (vm.newpassword_details.password.search("^(?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[$@£!%*#?&]).{8,}$")) {
  var msg = "Password should contain one special character from -'$@£!%*#?&' and at least one letter and number";
  alert(msg);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to limit the chars a user can use for a password? It is not best practice. You can achieve it with `/^(?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[$@£!%*#?&])[A-Za-z0-9$@£!%*#?&]{8,}$/` regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your current regex *imposes* 4 types of restriction:

1. At least one ASCII letter (`(?=.*?[A-Za-z])`),
2. At least one digit (`(?=.*?[0-9])`),
3. At least one specific char from the set (`(?=.*?[$@£!%*#?&])`)
4. The whole string should have at least 8 chars (`.{8,}`)

The `.` in `.{8,}` can match *any* char other than line break chars.

If you plan to restrict the `.` and only allow users to type the chars from your sets, create a superset from them and use it with `RegExp#test`:

```
if (!/^(?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[$@£!%*#?&])[A-Za-z0-9$@£!%*#?&]{8,}$/.test(vm.newpassword_details.password)) {  /* Error ! */  }
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SOpOju/1/)